# Удаление элементов из vector_pair

Tags: c++, vector

Я хочу удалить элементы v[i+1].first и v[i+1].second из vector_pair. Что нужно написать там где /// чтобы сделать это

```
vector <pair <string,int> > v;
int t,i,j;
cin>>t;
for(i=0; i<t; i++){
    string s;
    int n;
    cin>>s>>n;
    v.push_back(make_pair(s,n));
}
cout<<"\n";
sort(v.begin(),v.end());
for(i=0; i<v.size(); i++){
    if(v[i].first == v[i+1].first){
        v[i].second += v[i+1].second;
        ///
    }
}
```

Comment: `v.erase(v.begin()+i+1);` Только вот **что** вы проверяете, когда у вас `i==v.size()-1`?

Comment: если i == v.size()-1 я просто выйду из цикла

Comment: Нет, вы не выйдете из цикла, а будете обращаться к элементу `v[v.size()]` - убедитесь сами: `for(i=0; i<v.size(); i++){...` при `i==v.size()-1` условие цикла вполне выполняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы не хотите сделать так?

```
map<string,int> v;
int t,i,j;
cin>>t;
for(i=0; i<t; i++){
    string s;
    int n;
    cin>>s>>n;
    v[s]+=n;
}
```

И никаких лишних телодвижений не нужно...

Comment: наверное можно и так =) но я не очень хорошо знаю map))

Comment: Ну так самое время познакомиться с ним поближе!

Comment: и спасибо за то что всегда быстро отвечаете на мои вопросы)

Comment: ............хорошо))